# Vuejs и шаблон страницы ruby on rails

Tags: vue.js, ruby-on-rails, vuex

Имеется страница на руби (каталог с товарами), на ней есть фильтр (vue), как можно при выборе чекбокса из фильтра, подгружать товары, полученные из `api`?
В данный момент делаю следующим образом: при клике на чекбокс вызываю метод, который удаляет по классу сетку товаров.

```
if(document.querySelector('.shop-content__grid')) {
   document.querySelector('.shop-content__grid').classList.remove('shop-content__grid');
}
```

и подкидываю товары из `api`.

Да, всё отрабатывает, но, думаю, это не столь верно решение. Как сделать более правильно и чисто? Буду благодарен любой помощи.

Comment: У Вас же есть Vue, зачем Вы делаете костыль на чистом JS? И приведите пример кода, минимально описывающий проблему.

Comment: Хотя вообще, у Вас стандартный поток данных через data, метод с отправкой запроса к API (через axios, например) изменяет данные, а чекбоксы изменяют поведение data по v-model

Comment: @VladimirGonchar Проблема в том, что я не до конца понимаю, как убрать товары из руби шаблона, и подкинуть из апи. Без использования чистого JS

Comment: Формально Вы вообще не должны смешивать шаблоны при этом подходе. Т.е Выдолжны работать чисто с Vue на клиенте, а сервер у Вас выступает как API. При необходимости SSR (рендера страницы на стороне сервера) использовать Nuxt (простой вариант) или Vite (вариант для хардкорщиков). При любом другом исходе решение не будет правильным с точки зрения современного веба.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar Спасибо большое. Попробую протолкнуть данную идею в команде, можно ли сказать, что без ssr/nuxt/vite, мое решение подходит, но кастыльно? (в дальнейшем, будем фиксить с использованием Nuxt, вероятно)